# How to inherit OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter or add custom filter

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am using OAuth2 token in rest based API. I wanted to override OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter so that I can extract token if not provider in header attribute as Authorization(This could be provided as accessToken attribute in header long story don't ask why).
Or 
if not then can anyone tell me how to add another filter after the OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter ?

Comment: Did you try `.addFilterAfter(yourFilter, OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.class)` in `configure(HttpSecurity)`?

Comment: I am using xml namespace configuration how to do this in that config style.

Comment: Could you please show your spring security configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, in XML, to use the defaults, you add `resource-server`

```
<oauth:resource-server id="resourceServerFilter"
        token-services-ref="tokenServices"
        resource-id="myId" />
```

which adds `OAuth2AuthenticationManager` and `OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter` (see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/ec215f79f4f73f8bb5d4b8a3ff9abe15b3335866/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/config/xml/ResourceServerBeanDefinitionParser.java for details)

Then you add that filter into your `<sec:http>` element:

```
<sec:custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
```

But if you need to use `OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter` specialization instead of `OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter` itself, you could do the following:

I. Add `OAuth2AuthenticationManager` manually:

```
<bean id="authenticationManager" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.xml.OAuth2AuthenticationManager">
    <property name="tokenServices" ref="tokenServices"/>
    <property name="resourceId" value="myId"/>
</bean>
```

II. Add your filter replacement manually:

```
<bean id="resourceServerFilter"class="YourFilterImplementationClass">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
</bean>
```

III. Insert the filter to filter chain, as usual:

```
<sec:custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
```

Comment: <property name="resourceId" value="myId"/> why valye is myId here ? Tell me what should be the correct value for resourceId.

Comment: Any value you choose, but it has to be the same in `<resource-server>` and `authenticationManager` definition at server, and in the client definition (it's `resourceIds`): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8598960/what-does-resourceid-mean-in-oauth-2-0-with-spring-security

Answer (score 1):

A better approach could have been to  extend `org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.BearerTokenExtractor` and create bean for same and ref it in

```
<oauth:resource-server id="resourceServerFilter"
        token-services-ref="tokenServices" token-extractor-ref="idofyourtokenextractionbeanhere" 
        resource-id="myId" />
```

Comment: I was able to extract token in spring mvc doing this. thanks