# What is the resource_ids field for?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth

The [spring-security-oauth schema](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/test/resources/schema.sql) has a this table:

```
    create table oauth_client_details (
      client_id VARCHAR(256) PRIMARY KEY,
      resource_ids VARCHAR(256),
      client_secret VARCHAR(256),
      scope VARCHAR(256),
      authorized_grant_types VARCHAR(256),
      web_server_redirect_uri VARCHAR(256),
      authorities VARCHAR(256),
      access_token_validity INTEGER,
      refresh_token_validity INTEGER,
      additional_information VARCHAR(4096),
      autoapprove VARCHAR(256)
    );
```

What is the `resource_ids` column for?  There is a [related question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8598960/what-does-resourceid-mean-in-oauth-2-0-with-spring-security) but it's not clear from the answers whether `resource_ids` perform the same function as scopes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [developer guide](https://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html),

`resource_id`: the id for the resource (optional, but recommended and will be validated by the auth server if present)